# Can a python module be a variable?

Tags: python, import, module

I have a Settings.py file and Test files that call from it, and different Functions files that Settings.py and the Test files call from.

I want to be able to choose which Functions file (Fun1.py, Fun2.py) to import depending on a variable in Settings.py

I know I can do something like this:

```
# Settings.py
Version = 1
if Version == 1:
    import Fun1 as Functions
elif Version == 2:
    import Fun2 as Functions
else:
    print "Invalid Version"

# Test1.py
import Settings
if Settings.Version == 1:
    import Fun1 as Functions
elif Settings.Version == 2:
    import Fun2 as Functions
else:
    print "Invalid Version"
```

But I don't want to have this if statement across all of my Test files.  I would prefer to just edit one variable and the correct version is used across my scripts.

I tried this and python didn't allow it, so wondering if there's an alternative.

```
# Settings.py
Fun_File = Fun1
import Fun_File

# Test1.py
import Settings
myFile= Settings.Fun_File
import myFile as Functions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's way simpler than that. Just use the first version of `Settings.py` and

```
from Settings import Functions
```

to import whatever module you configured

(Also, you really shouldn't name your modules in uppercase.)

Comment: Awesome, that seems to work, thanks!
Why no uppercase for module naming?

Comment: @user12728757: Standard convention is lowercase. Naming your modules in uppercase makes them look like classes, making your code harder to read.